# Azure DevOps Git subtree

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, jira, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Is it possible to setup git subtrees across repositories within the Azure DevOps ecosystem. The reason I am asking is I have a project that builds by pulling in branch artefacts from shared repositories which works fine but Jira integration does not fully function because those artefacts aren't tied to pull requests and subsequently ticket numbers.

Jira hooks into the releases from Azure Devops but cannot tie it back to the original ticket due to the pull requests being in a different repository.

I believe if I can get subtrees to work than all my pipelines/release configuration can be from one repository integrated to Jira thus ensuring full ticket traceability.